# Google Trusted Stores Shipmet feed Carrier in Magento

Tags: magento, trusted, google-trusted-stores

i have an issue with the feed that is sent to my google merchant account (order_shipments.txt) there is 4 columns

merchant order id
tracking number
carrier code
other carrier name
ship date

i have set my shipping as FREE SHIPPING with the shipping magento method for Free Shipping, the problem is that under my feed all the tracking numbers shows as carrier (other) and i need under my feed on carrier either UPS or USPS. because every time we ship an order we enter the tracking number and the carrier for the shipment. any suggestion will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm not too late!

We just patched this exact issue (as well as others) and have documented the necessary modifications at http://www.dcjcooltools.com/blog/magento-extensions/the-nightmare-that-is-google-trusted-stores-for-magento/

Look for the post in the comments that discusses carrier names.  We are looking to create a patch extension so that you don't have to modify core Trusted Stores files.

Let me know if this solution works for you!

Regards,
Evan